# citation for function findHomography of OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Could someone help me with the citation information of this function of OpenCV? I think rather this is a standard algorithm in literature, there should still be some source of citation since I don't know which one is actually implemented here

Thank you very much!

Comment: there are two different methods implemented, LMEDS and RANSAC, so there are at least two different cirations possible. The RANSAC version is described in zisserman's multi-view-geometry book, but I xan't guarantee that it is implemented 1:1

Comment: it's hard to know which algorithms are implemented unless there's a confirm from the OpenCV developers. Some new functions have this claim in the official documentations but I  found findHomography to be quite old. Or perhaps I just cite 3 of them? RANSAC/LMEDS and standard geometrical technique for homography estimation itself

Comment: have a look at the source code (it is open), sometimes there are papers linked in the code. Or you have to understand the code to be certain.